# Lost column definitions with joins, in twig

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.2

I've got a query set up in doctrine that I'm confident does what it's supposed to...it joins several tables so we can skip a bunch of extra queries to get data through foreign keys:

```
$posts = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
        ->createQuery('
            SELECT a AS article, COUNT(c) AS comments
            FROM ArticleBundle:Article a
                LEFT JOIN CommentsBundle:Comment c WITH (c.article = a.id)
                LEFT JOIN ImageBundle:Image i WITH (i.id = a.image)
            GROUP BY a.id
            ORDER BY a.timestamp DESC
        ')
        ->getResult();
```

I'm able to access the data quite succesfully, like so:

```
{% for post in posts %}
<div id="news-story">
 <div class="title">{{ post.article.title }}</div>
 <div class="comments">{{ post.comments }}</div>
 ...
{% endfor %}
```

The issue is, as soon as I add a second column ("i AS image") to the field list, it fails.  I get the following message...

> Item "article" for "Array" does not exist in ...

...and I can't quite figure out why.  I would hope that I would be able to access the variables like {{ post.article.title }} and {{ post.image.path }} (which does exist, by the way)...but I can't.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm still a beginner to symfony2, but i could tell you that maybe if u dump the post you'll understand the issue, put {{ dump(post) }} http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html

Comment: Do you have a relationship between the image entity, and article entity?

Comment: Yep! The article entity has a OneToOne relationship on a column named "image" to the image entity.

Comment: tMohammad: Thanks for that.  I checked it and, interestingly, it actually looks okay.  Very confusing.

Comment: See my answer, but in your example, image would be accessed by using `{{ post.article.image.path }}` because it is associated with article, and doctrine will wire up your associations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your confusion arises from the fact that you have created a query that returns a scalar result: `COUNT(c)...` along with objects.

This means that instead of returning an array of `Article` entities, as you expect (you are trying to use `post.image`) you actually get an associative array, where each member contains the count - `post.comments` and the article entity `post.article`.

n.b. If you want to access images associated with the article, you will need to use `post.article.image`.

I'll try and illustrate:

Your expecting an array of article objects that you can iterate over:

```
array(
    [0] => ArticleEntity,
    [1] => ArticleEntity,
    [2] => ArticleEntity
)
```

What you actually get from your query

```
array(
    [0] => array(
        'article' => ArticleEntity,
        'comments'=> 10
    ),
    [1] => array(
        'article' => ArticleEntity,
        'comments'=> 3
    ),
    [2] => array(
        'article' => ArticleEntity,
        'comments'=> 0
    )
)
```

If you remove the scalar part of your query `COUNT(c) AS comments` then you will get the first example, leave it in and you will get the second example.

The [Doctrine documentation on pure/mixed results](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#pure-and-mixed-results) is some good reading/explanation on this.

As a side note is there any reason you are writing raw SQL. For a start you can re-write the query using DQL to leverage some of the power Doctrine offers.

```
$qb = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->createQueryBuilder();

$qb
    ->select('article', 'image', 'COUNT(comments) as comment_count')
    ->from('ArticleBundle:Article', 'article')
    ->leftJoin('article.comment', 'comments')
    ->leftJoin('article.image', 'image')
    ->groupBy('article.id')
    ->orderBy('article.timestamp', 'DESC')
;

$posts = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: Fantastic and very informative.  Just what I was looking for.  Thanks!